# Syntax for casting a receiver in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a class/super class pair declared thus:

```
@class WSStatement;
@interface WSIfStatement : WSStatement
@property (nonatomic, retain) WSStatement *thenstatement;
@end
```

I create an instance of the subclass using Core Data and assign it to a WSStatement * pointer (i.e. the super class).  At some later point I want to send a message to the object that is specific to the subclass, and the compiler is giving me a warning saying "instance method not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

I have tried casting like this ....

```
[(WSIfStatement *)statement setThenStatement:aVariableParameter];
```

but the warning persists.  The program executes perfectly, but I can't rid myself of the pesky compiler warning.  I couldn't find a complete formal Objective-C syntax description anywhere, so I apologise if the answer is obvious!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not a typo then the problem is you are calling the wrong method.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) WSStatement *thenstatement;

//Will be called with a lowercase s for statement
[(WSIfStatement *)statement setThenstatement:aVariableParameter];
```

Also you can not just forward declare a class that you inherit from. You will need to include the header for `WSStatement`. And if you still have an error make sure you synthesize `thenstatement` in the implementation.

Comment: Thanks Joe - as always - the obvious things are the easiest to miss!  It was the lower case s in the property declaration for thenStatement.  It arose because this is a generated class from Core Data and although I had changed the case in the core data modelling tool, I had forgotten to regenerate the model classes.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you synthesised the properties?  In you .m file use:

```
@synthesize thenstatement;
```

This will generate the set function.

Comment: Why has this been down-voted?  You will get this error if you don't synthesize the property.  thenStatement and setThenStatement would not exist.

Comment: Maybe because you had a typo, `#synthesize` instead of `@synthesize`. Still not worth a down vote.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but a comment from the guy would have been enough for me to fix it.  I've fixed it now.  Sorry for the typo and thanks for pointing it out.  Damn French-Canadian keyboards.

Comment: I was not the down voter but I agree [drive by down votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) are annoying.

Comment: You still have two typos: 1) it's `thenstatement`, not `thenStatement` in the OP's code, and 2) you're missing your terminating semi-colon. Fix those and I'll upvote ya.

Comment: Not even clang can check the syntax of my stackoverflow code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `#import "WSIfStatement.h"` to your .m file where you're making that call.